# Using a string variable inside a view component result in "Unexpected text node"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm new to react native and java script. I want to design a simple calculator using react native (with expo) and this is my render for showing buttons:

```
render() {
    let views = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputButtons.length; i++) {
      let row = inputButtons[i];
      let rowViews = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        rowViews.push(
          <View style={styles.button} key={"r" + i + "c" + j}>
            {row[j]}
          </View>
        );
      }
      views.push(<View style={styles.buttonRow} key={"r" + i}>{rowViews}</View>);
    }

    return (<View style={styles.containter}>{views}</View>);
  }
```

when I only have numbers in inputButttons variable everything is fine:

```
const inputButtons = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [0]
];
```

but when I add characters or strings like this then it gives me errors:

```
const inputButtons = [
    [1, 2, 3, '/'],
    [4, 5, 6, '*'],
    [7, 8, 9, '-'],
    [0, '.', '=', '+']
];
```

```
×
←→1 of 6 errors on the page
Unexpected text node: +. A text node cannot be a child of a <View>.
▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
fn
src/components/NumberButtons/index.js:40
  37 |       views.push(<View style={styles.buttonRow} key={"r" + i}>{rowViews}</View>);
  38 |     }
  39 | 
> 40 |     return (<View style={styles.containter}>{views}</View>);
  41 |   }
  42 | }
  43 | 
View compiled
▶ 4 stack frames were collapsed.
```

I will be glad if someone tell me what's wrong with this.

Comment: "A text node cannot be a child of a <View>". But that's what you were doing. The question is, why numbers worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put strings inside  tag

```
<View style={styles.button} key={"r" + i + "c" + j}>
      <Text>{row[j]}</Text>
</View>
```